# How to install postgresql on FreeBSD

Tags: installation, postgresql, freebsd

Here is a step-by-step description of what I am doing

- cd /usr/ports/databases/postgresql91-server/
- make install clean
- adding `postgresql_enable="YES"`  to `/etc/rc.conf`
- trying to start `sudo /usr/local/etc/rc.d/postgresql onsestart`.

After all of these steps, however, I still get the message:

> postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory

What step am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that path is valid and that file exists?

Comment: @Shads0 - i'm not a seasoned BSD user at all, but as far as I understand this very file (which is missing) should be created by the launcher with respect to the postgresql_enable="YES" in rc.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run `initdb` before you can use a postgres server.  This can't be done for you as it would destroy your existing database if you were doing an upgrade.

`/usr/local/etc/rc.d/postgresql initdb` will do what you need if you are using a FreeBSD port, otherwise see the [`initdb` man page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-initdb.html).

(Also note that the port's post-install message tells you this - The messages ports print out after you run `make install` are generally important :)

Comment: shame on me, you are right, i should read whatever the terminal says more carefully.

Comment: The first clobbering is free :) (I'm also a little touchy about it because I maintain a few ports - we really do try hard to include all the important stuff in those post-install messages…)